# On changing href value to popupid not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created some blocks which have different descriptions which should be printed,so i have created all the popup details separately and made the print button with "#" on load and on clicking on blocks i have tried to change the href value to the corresponding popupid.After this change in href value on clicking print popup is not showing. Following  the codes i have used:

```
<div id ="9print">
<a class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-square vc_btn3-style-classic vc_btn3-color-grey" href="#" title="">PRINT</a>
</div>
```

onclick button 9

```
$("#9print a").prop("href", "#sg-popup-id-429");
```

the href value is changing to "#sg-popup-id-429", but after that when i click on "PRINT" popup is not showing , if we directly put the href value as "#sg-popup-id-429" its working fine

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: How do you open the popup? Is this another event that is added to the anchor tag? Could you add this code?

Comment: if i click on a button and its href="#sg-popup-id-429" in this way i could open the popup

Comment: plz share your javascript where is your `onchange()` fn

Comment: $( "#9A" ).click(function() {
$("#9print a").prop("href", "#sg-popup-id-429");
});

Comment: But could you show the code that opens the popup as well?

Comment: no if i click on 9A,"#sg-popup-id-429" should shown if i click 9B "#sg-popup-id-430" should shown like wise

Comment: Why won't you just show the popup event code? I think it has to do with when the event is created.

Answer (score -1):

It's because the href property contains more then just "#". It contains the full url. You can make it work by replacing the last part of the url.

The regex `/#.*/` works as follows.

- `#` matches the # character
- `.*` matches (almost) any character 0-unlimited times

```js
var currHref = $("#9print a").prop("href");
$("#9print a").prop("href", currHref.replace(/#.*/, "#sg-popup-id-429"));

//code for showing initial and new href values.
var newHref = $("#9print a").prop("href");
console.log("initial href: " + currHref);
console.log("new href: " + newHref);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="9print">
<a class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-square vc_btn3-style-classic vc_btn3-color-grey" href="#" title="">PRINT</a>
</div>

<div style="height: 2000px;"></div>

<div id="sg-popup-id-429" style="height: 100px; background-color: red">test<div>
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all I would place this inside the [document ready function](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) in jquery, so you don't run the jQuery function you're trying to invoke on an element that is not yey loaded on your page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#9print a").click(function() {
        $("#9print a").attr("href", "#sg-popup-id-429");
    });
});
```

This is just assuming, that this is your problem :) Show more of your code if this did not help at all :)

Comment: this ready function is there already i just put the click function code

Comment: you shouldn't use `click()`. `on()` is the way to go these days. Beside that you shouldn't need the click event handler.

Comment: @user11196214 - fair enough. But I cannot read that from your example :) you still did not answer if the function worked.

Comment: @MarkBaijens - ok, but does utilizing a function that is not deprecated in jQuery really deserve a downvote? And why shouldn't one need a click event handler? As far as I can read from the question he wants to change the href attribute when the link is clicked? Am I missing something really obvious here?